# what is the source of arrayQualityMetrics package and GEOquery for the R 3.6

Tags: r, linux, windows

Every time i try to install a new package in R 3.6, an error appear, so i need to know the source of both 'arrayQualityMetrics'  and 'GEOquery' package for R 3.6

Answer (score 0):

the source of biological packages for r (such as arrayQualityMetrics package and GEOquery) is bioconductor website (https://bioconductor.org/)

install arrayQualityMetrics package in r v3.6:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("arrayQualityMetrics")
```

install GEOquery package in r `v3.6`:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
```

install arrayQualityMetrics package in `r v3.4`:

```
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("arrayQualityMetrics")
```

install GEOquery package in `r v3.4`:

```
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("GEOquery")
```

install biological package in Previous Releases:

solution 1:at the following link choose your r version, then search the packages.
[install biological package for Previous Releases r](https://www.bioconductor.org/install/#install-bioconductor-packages)
.

[image: biological package for Previous Releases r]

install biological package in Previous Releases:

solution 2:

```
setRepositories()
1 2
install.packages("arrayQualityMetrics")
install.packages("GEOquery")
```

Comment: > if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+     install.packages("BiocManager")
Installing package into '/home/refka/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'BiocManager' is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
> 
> BiocManager::install("arrayQualityMetrics")
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'BiocManager'                                              i already tried with the bioconductor installation but i receive the above message (error ,,,

Comment: @RefkaBenHamouda The error message indicates that you are using R 3.4.4 while you questions says R 3.6. Which is correct?

Comment: as @ Ralf Stubner mentioned, your r version is 3.4. you could update your r version to v3.6 or use the codes for `r v3.4` that I inserted to the answer.